# Замена img тегов

Tags: img, регулярные-выражения, замена, php

Такая ситуация, есть переменная с текстом:

```
<img src="./images/fix_position.jpg" height="24"> 
<img src="./images/fix_position.jpg" height="24"> 
<img class="test" src="./images/etc_0.jpg">
<img src="./images/fix_position.jpg">
<img class="test" src="./images/etc_1.jpg">
```

Мне нужно с помощью регулярных выражений автоматический сделать:

```
<img src="./images/1.jpg" height="24"> 
<img src="./images/2.jpg" height="24"> 
<img class="test" src="./images/3.jpg">
<img src="./images/4.jpg">
<img class="test" src="./images/5.jpg">
```

Подскажите какие-нибудь простенькие примеры на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1;
$html = preg_replace_callback('/src=".*?"/', function() {
    global $i;
    return 'src="./images/'.($i++).'.jpg"';

}, $html);
```

Либо

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("img") as $count => $link) {
    $link->setAttribute("src", "./images/".($count).".jpg");
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```